# How to test with phpunit this class, which uses connections to the database

Tags: php, phpunit, integration-testing

I have read in another document that classes which have methods with connections to a database have to be tested by integration tests. I tried to find an example, but I didn't find any, only theory. I've very little experience with testing. Can you give me an example? a link?, something (instead of only theory, because I read a lot), with something like this?. I think this is not an strange case. If its possible with php and sql or similar.

If you dont know about integration tests, how do you test this kinds of problems?

```
class database{

public $server;
public $database;
public $password;
public $user;
public $descriptor;


function __construct(){
$this->server="localhost";
$this->database="mydb";
$this->user="stackoverflow";
$this->password="1234";

$this->descriptor=mysql_connect($this->server,$this->user,$this->password);
mysql_select_db($this->database,$this->descriptor); 
}


function make_request($query){
$response=mysql_query($query,$this->descriptor);
return $response;
}


function close_connection(){
mysql_close($this->descriptor);
}

function number_rows($result_query){
return mysql_num_rows($result_query);
}

}
```

Comment: I found this article, in the section "testing databases" but without example, only theory. In this article you can read that is better, in this case, using PDO. But even with that.......for me is not enough.
http://erichogue.ca/2011/06/php/test-driven-development-in-php/

Comment: Post one of the methods you're trying to test so we have an idea of how your particular data layer API looks.

Answer (score 4):

Look into [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/goals.html) for unit testing. You can then use [mock objects](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/mock-objects.html) to simulate the dependencies (DB calls) to return dummy data. Because you're trying to test some unit of logic and not that your database layer, it should be acceptable and give you a reasonable amount of confidence that your code is working.

Another option is to use integration tests, but this requires that you put a lot of effort into the setup and teardown of your tests. You need to make sure any data required for your tests exists within your database. It's common to use transactions for these types of tests which you can then rollback after your finished running those tests.

Comment: so, by using mock objects I need to use something like PDO?, with OOP as well no?. I suppose with PDO must be easier to pupulate the mock objects with dummy data no?

Comment: You use mock objects to simulate any dependency which can be PDO. So instead of calling `$PDO->query()` on an actual PDO object, you call it on the mock object which returns pre configured results.

Answer (score 1):

Which code is it you're trying to test? Is it the code that uses your `database` class? If so, you don't need to introduce PDO, as your `database` class already provides an abstraction (well, it would be much safer if `public $descriptor` was private). So, you should start by mocking your `database` class and then testing the code that uses it. PHPUnit has a [sophisticated mocking system](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-doubles.html).

Another thing you might want to be testing is this `database` class itself? In that case you'll have to accept the MySQL database dependency, and the speed hit that gives you. Set up a completely dedicated MySQL database for that testing. If you don't mind the speed hit, consider creating the database in a `setUp()` function and removing it after each test in a `tearDown()` function.

The third thing you might want to be testing is that your website (or whatever) works as a whole, and connects to the database, etc. This is functional testing (also called integration testing). If your system offers a web services API, then you could use that to test it. Otherwise you could use Selenium (still using PHPUnit) to test by remote control of a real browser. If your tests will only read from the database, you could use your live system; but it would be much more sensible to assume a write will happen at some point, so test against a test version of the website, with its own dedicated test database.

The advantage of functional testing is it high level, testing for all interactions between components, testing the system as the end user will use it. The downside is when a test fails it only tells you something is wrong, not exactly which component is to blame. So we have unit tests to test each component in isolation.

I know you this is more text, less code, than you wanted! But you have actually asked quite a theoretical question! Just try setting up some unit tests of this code, watch what problems occur over the first month of using them, and you'll understand why and where to use mocks.